# How to specify which method Java use?

Tags: java, list, integer

Now I have an `ArrayList<Integer>`.
As [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get%28int%29) says, there are two remove methods for ArrayList.
Suppose I have an integer 2, I want to remove the ELEMENT 2 in that list rather than the element on POSITION 2(third element), how should I tell Java to do so?

Comment: Presumably, you would use `int` to remove by index and `Integer` to remove the value.  The real question is, what have you tried

Comment: I have tried using ArrayList.remove with merely an primitive integer, and the compiler would interpret it as using the remove(Object o). My bad, I should supplement this detail.

Comment: @Patashu : Thanks for you editing! I forgot to add the <Integer> part which have definitely caused some confusion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a problem related to [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html). Actually, when `T == Integer`, you have two remove methods:

- `void remove(int index)`
- `void remove(Integer object)`

Just force the compiler to choose the appropriate, object based, version by casting it to an `Integer` or by using directly an `Integer`:

```
list.remove((Integer)2);
list.remove(Integer.valueOf(2));
```

Comment: Great answer. I'm wondering why you edited out the (new Integer(2)) choice..Does that not work?

Comment: `(Integer)2` and `Integer.valueOf(2)` both are `Integer`, not `int`. What's the difference in `list.remove method`.

Comment: @octref: it's just a matter of taste. I usually use `new Integer(..)` but both are equal.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `public boolean remove(Object o)` method to remove object from list. in your case you should write statement as `this.remove(new Integer(2));`